# Adaptedness of random step process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose you are given a random stem process of the form
$$
f(t) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\eta_j \mathbb{1}_{[t_j, t_{j+1})}(t),
$$
where $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n$ and $\eta_1, \eta_2, \cdots \eta_{j-1}$ are square integrable random variables. The book I am reading claims that if $\eta_j$ are $\mathcal{F}_{t_j}$-measurable, then $f(t)$ is adapted to the filtration $\mathcal{F_t}$. Why is this true? Note that filtrations here are defined with respect to the Wiener process, i.e.,
$$
 \mathcal{F}_s = \sigma\{W(r): 0 \le r \le s\}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $t_{j_0}\leqslant t<t_{j_0+1}$ for some $j_0\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$. Then
$f(t)=\eta_{j_0}$ if $j_0\geqslant 1$ and $0$ if $j_0=0$; in any case, $f(t)$ is $\mathcal F_{t_{j_0}}$-measurable and the inclusion $\mathcal F_{t_{j_0}}\subset \mathcal F_t$ guarantees that $f(t)$ is $\mathcal F_t$-measurable.

Comment: So the case of $t > t_n$ is simply resolved as f(t) is zero and this function is clearly $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}$